# Curious HTML phenomenon in PHP 'if' condition

Tags: php, html, if-statement

i have the following html code. the main goal is to hide a div when a variable from the php part is set to "s2" i'm using this code:

```
<?php if(isset($Status) && $Status =="S0" OR $Status =="S2"):?>

    <?php if(isset($Status) && $Status=="S0"): ?>
        <div>
            <label for="x1">x1</label>  
            <select name="x1"  id="x1">
            <option value="<?php echo $x1;?>"></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
           some more divs
    <?php endif; ?>
```

the curoius thing about that is when i change:

```
<?php if(isset($Status) && $Status=="S0"): ?>
            <div>
                <label for="x1">x1</label>  
                <select name="x1"  id="x1">
                <option value="<?php echo $x1;?>"></option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

to:

```
        <div>
            <label for="x1">x1</label>  
            <select style="display:<?php echo ($Status == "S2" ? 'none' : 'inline'); ?>;" name="x1"  id="x1">
            <option value="<?php echo $x1;?>"></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

everything works. the phenomenon is that when i will submit the form i get an errormessage that there are no entries even it is filled an php echo from the db when using the first code. using the last code means, everything works and errormessages for example will be displayed. so this is a little bit strange to me. the different kinds of status will be set in the db so thats not the problem. the query i tested also. i also tried just to show the divs i like to have when S0 is given:

```
<?php if(isset($Status) && $Status =="S0"):?>
```

and the divs that just should be visible when s2 is given:

```
<?php if(isset($Status) && $Status =="S2"):?>
```

is anybody out there, who can tell me what am i doing wrong? thanks alot.

**UPDATE:**

okay, first of all thanks for answering my question.

i added the brackets and changed && to "and".

the problem seems to be the value with that line:

```
<option value="<?php echo $x1;?>"></option>
```

in my opinion even when a user can't see the first item because of:

```
...?>">NOTHING IN HERE</option>
```

the value for "NOTHING IN HERE" should be the echo of the db. so that should submit the echo value or am i wrong?

the errormessage that occurs and why nothing will be submitted says that the field is empty. but from my point of view it isn't?!

just to point out why i'm not want to display the first entry:

i dont like it when a user sees the drop down list and there will be a double post like:

drop down list on click:

```
1 ->because this echoes the entry of the db.
1 ->first option
2 ->second option
```

Comment: 2 purely semantic things; (1) don't mix `&&` with `OR`, either use `&& ||` or `AND OR` (2) always use brackets when you're writing IFs with both AND and OR, even when you don't think they're necessary - in 6 months time, you'll wish you had :)

Comment: You conditional is *still* wrong. `and` has a higher priority than `or`, so you need to use parentheses: For instance `isset($Status) and ($Status =="S0" or $Status =="S2")`

Comment: If the problem *is* that you have nothing inside the `<option>` element then you can test it by adding some fixed text there. I understand that you don't want the contents of the database to be visible but the user ought to see something. The value transmitted on *submit* will be the `value` property of the tag.

Answer (score 1):

You should correct the 1st line this way:

```
<?php if(isset($Status) && ($Status =="S0" OR $Status =="S2")):?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few things wrong with your code but nothing that I think would cause what you describe, although I am unclear which of your examples causes the *no entries* error message.

Firstly you are mixing `&&` with `OR` which is causing the expression to be evaluated differently from what you expect. The text logical operators (`and` and `or`) are identical to the symbolic ones (`&&` and `||`) except for their *precedence*. The text operators are grouped *after* the syymbolic ones, so you have

```
if((isset($Status) && $Status =="S0") OR $Status =="S2")
```

which you should rewrite as

```
if(isset($Status) and $Status =="S0" || $Status =="S2")
```

or use parentheses to force the priority

```
if(isset($Status) and ($Status =="S0" or $Status =="S2"))
```

Secondly you have missed the text out of the x1 option, so instead of

```
<option value="<?php echo $x1;?>"></option>
```

you should have

```
<option value="<?php echo $x1;?>"><?php echo $x1;?></option>
```

otherwise nothing will appear in the drop-down list.

Otherwise I can see nothing that would cause what you describe. Please clarify which code gives you the error.